# Do not display the entire contents of an EditText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

What I do is to not display the entire contents of an EditText ... I have a String too long and I would love for you only see three dots.

Anyone know how to do?

Comment: This doesn't really make much sense - an `EditText` is meant to be used so a user can edit the text (as the name suggests). If the user can't see all of the text, how are they supposed to edit it?

Comment: In my application I take the value of a bar code and took him to an EditText, there will be that EditText disabled, the value of the bar code is very long, so I need to show only part of it

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to display text and don't want the user to edit it use a `TextView` instead of an `EditText`.

In the XML layout file just use the [android:ellipsize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aellipsize) attribute to get it to truncate the text and add '...'.

Comment: TextView.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
As shown I can do characters that I want

Comment: The full text shows only three dots when placed under the scroll.. :'(

Comment: setMaxLines(1); its show 1 line... and dont show all contein.

Answer (score 0):

Get the text from the edittext and save it as a String variable. Then you can just use some logic in Java to do the rest.

```
int maxLength = AMOUNT_YOU_WANT_TO_BE_THE_MAXIMUM;
if(String.length() > maxLength)
    EditText.text = EditText.text.substring(0, maxLength) + "...";
```

I'm assuming you know how to get the text of the EditText field. If not, just ask.

Comment: the answer is fine, but the value of my EditText will change ... the value of my EditText which contains a long string, showing only part + ..., but its value changes.

Comment: In that case, can't you just keep track of a local variable that holds onto the actual String? The next time someone tries to edit the text again, you can just quickly substitute in the old string to solve that problem.